# Symfony2 prePersist not fired when persisting entity

Tags: symfony, orm, annotations, doctrine, symfony-2.1

I followed this tutorial: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html#using-lifecycle-callbacks

However **prePersist** is not fired (but entity is persisted to database).

```
   $media = new Media();
   $form = $this->createFormBuilder($media)
            ->add('file')
            ->getForm();

        if ($request->isMethod("POST")) {
            $form->bindRequest($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

                $em->persist($media);
                $em->flush();
            }
    }
```

**Entity:** http://dpaste.com/869771/ (some of the code I just copied and pasted into my class)

I added

```
die("test");
```

to the upload function but it is not called. So whats wrong? Any ideas? I am using sf 2.1.

Comment: So explain again where the database mapping happens?  If the mapping is done in an xml file then the annotations won't do you any good.  Can't mix and match.  Need to add the lifecycle mappings to your xml file.

Comment: Your dpaste code has expired, severing the usefulness of your question. Please don't use external links and do include code in the question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the code you pasted in pastebin is accurate then the problem is that you are trying to mix xml mappings and annotation mappings.  You need to use one method or another.

This link: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html

shows how to add life cycle mappings to an xml file.

Comment: Thanks, I added this to my xml and no it works just fine!! :)

Answer (score 1):

> However prePersist is not fired... to the upload function

It is not fired because you are using a **PostPersist()** on upload() method and not a **PrePersist()**

PostPersist is fired after saving, while PrePersist is fired before saving !
So You will see "die" after saving and not before.

In addition, when using PrePersist, your entity will not have an id yet, while with a PostPersist it will have an id assigned.

Comment: Did you look at http://dpaste.com/869771/ ? at PrePersist I have die too, however it does not trigger

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think that because your **Media** entity doesn't have any mapped fields the events are ignored.
Try mapping the `name` field for example to see if it's working.
Also, read about [Tracking Policies](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/change-tracking-policies.html).

Comment: what do you mean with mapping? The entity is generated using doctrine from an xml file

Comment: Does your form have more fields other than `file`?

Comment: So try adding a form field (with some value) for the `name` field. I know that **Update** events do not fire if the entity has not changed, so I want to check if that's the case here.

Comment: Tried, no difference. Still die("test") is not called